# Transparency between UITableViewCells

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I want to have transparency between UITableViewCells. Space between the cells.

I user custom created cells and for setting a background i use this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CustomCell = @"CustomBookingCell";

    currentBooking = [arrayBookings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CustomBookingCell *cell = (CustomBookingCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCell];

    if (cell == nil) {

        UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomBookingCell" bundle:nil];
        cell = (CustomBookingCell *)c.view;
        [ c release ];
    }



    bookingImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                     [UIImage imageNamed:currentBooking.imageSource]];

    [cell.imageForBooking addSubview:bookingImage];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


    UIView* backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    UIImage* bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background_300_82.png"];
    UIColor *bgColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage: bgImage];

    backgroundView.backgroundColor = bgColor;
    cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
    cell.label.text = currentBooking.title;

    [bookingImage release];
    [bgColor release];
    [backgroundView release];


    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 90;
}
```

The height of the cell is 10 pixels higher that the tableCellBg.png.
My background view has also a image as background (this background is supposed to be shown between the cells of course).

So I tried to add 10 pixels with transparency to my tableCellBg.png in the bottom to fix this. But the space between the cells is black. I can't see the view background between my cells.

What shall I do? Do I have to create a UIView in cellForRowAtIndexPath with the height of the tableCellBg.png and then add the Custom UITableViewCell as subview to the created UIView with a less higher height?

Or is there a much more simplyfied way to accomplish this?

Comment: I have tried to create a image which is black and then I've increased the canvaz size  and added 10 pixels of transparency. But this transparency becomes black, it's like transparency images isn't supported by UITableViewCell backgroundView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using another method to add the background image to the UITableViewCell:

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ny_bg_event.png"];
UIImageView  *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 84);
cell.backgroundView = imageView;
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[imageView release];

[cell setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 84)];

cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Instead of creating a UIView I just used a UIImageView instead.

Answer (score 5):

Your table view needs a clear background colour. For example

```
myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: The background images is by the way 82 pixels height.